# Cook a frozen cobbler in a microwave instead of oven

Tags: dessert, microwave, frozen

Here's my problem. We don't have access to a oven (we are out of town for a week and out hotel room only has a microwave and a 2 range stove top). I purchased a frozen Blackberry Cobbler and we want to make it. Does anyone know how long I should cook it and is it safe?

Answer (score 2):

It would almost certainly be safe, as there is nothing in a cobbler that could not be eaten if you just thawed the cobbler and ate it raw.

It is unlikely to be as good as when cooked properly in an oven because:

- The topping will not crisp up
- The microwave will not cook evenly, and you cannot stir a cobbler; you will most likely end up with cooler spots where any thickeners in the filling didn't gel, and still taste a little starchy, and other spots where the fruit is overcooked

It is not really possible to give you a time to use because, even if there was some sort of "oven to microwave" conversion factor (which there is not):

- Microwaves vary in power output
- The size of the cobbler in question will make a big difference

If you can take it home frozen, I would cook and eat it at home once you have access to a normal oven.

Comment: Related to the safety angle, I think if I *really* wanted to use the microwave and didn't have access to an oven, I'd just let it thaw on the counter before heating it in the microwave. At least it will cook more evenly that way, even though it still won't crisp and probably won't be great in general.

Comment: Also, depending on the topping, it may be not really palatable.  An oatmeal topping may get mushy in the 'nuking or it could turn into bits of concrete.  I go along with @SAJ14SAJ and recommend taking it home frozen if you can or if you are willing to risk wasting the money you spend on it, go ahead and try cooking it in the microwave and see what happens.  Good luck!

Comment: I'll suggest turning down the power on the microwave. That'll help a lot with the unevenness. Also, beware if the cobbler is in a foil pan, the foil will block the microwaves—or worse, start arcing. You will need to transfer it to a microwave-safe pan.